# WKWebView moves content viewport when resized on device rotation

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview, webkit

I'm using a WKWebView in my app and whenever I rotate my device, the content in the webView will move around. Then when I rotate back, the content moves again but not to where it was originally. I'm trying to get the feel of Safari on iOS, but the websites just don't zoom and rotate properly in the WKWebView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.hackster.io/projects")!)
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let content = WKUserContentController()

    content.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: try! String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script.js", ofType: nil)!), injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true))
    config.userContentController = content

    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.load(request)

    view.addSubview(webView)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        self.webView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Then the script.js file contains this.

```
var m = document.createElement("meta")
m.setAttribute("name", "viewport")
m.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes")
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(m)
```

script.js is just used to allow zooming.